# Laravel Eloquent - Array in a Nested Relation, how to assign it?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent, nested

I have a game database where a match have two teams (team_home_id and team_away_id). Users can make predictions for those games.

So the model Match has this:

```
public function teamHome()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Team::class, 'team_home_id');
}

public function teamAway()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Team::class, 'team_away_id');
}
```

I want to get all predictions from a specific user for this match. The prediction model have a polymorhpic table (because there are predictions for match and predictions for overall season).

In controller I do this:

```
        $matches = Match::where('match_day', $match_day)->with('teamHome', 'teamAway', 'predictions')->get();

foreach ($matches as $match) {

    echo $match->teamHome->code . '-';
    echo $match->teamAway->code . '  ';
   // echoing is just for testing purpose
    //dd($match->predictions); // this is the problem, what is the best way?
}
```

I got an array with the predictions that I'm not able to assign to specific user or only with manual foreach and assign it to a different array. But I don't think this would be a good way.

How I can solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to solve your problem. This is just one:

You can use a constraining eager load, that is, "only bring predictions that are from user X".

```php
$matches = Match::where('match_day', $match_day)
   ->with('teamHome', 'teamAway')
   ->with(['predictions' => function($prediction) use($userId){
      $prediction->where('user_id', '=', $userId);
   }])
   ->get();
```

[Source](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)

Comment: Thank you. Then I get an array of predictions like $match->predictions [i]. But this is wrong: a match indeed have more predictions (from different users) but in this case I should get $match->prediction->team_home. How I can avoid an array? I can't use first in the constraint. Should I change the relationship in the model? Or a where clause in the constraint with a "predictable_id = $match_id"?

Comment: Now I added morphOne() to "Match" model. But the logic seems not correct for me because a match has more than one prediction? Or am I thinking wrong? Should a match not have more predictions (from more users?)